# J2me on Mac OS Monterey

Tags: macos, sdk, java-me, j2mepolish

I wonder if there is a possible way to get working Java me sdk on recent Mac OS (12) natively. Last official version of sdk is from 2009 and won't launch, probably because of 32 bit architecture. If there is no way to do that, I'll use boot camp.